# Django raise IntegrityError exception befor form.save()

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model with a unique "code" field and a form for the same model where the "code" field is hidden. I need to set the "code" value in the view after the user has copied the form, but I get an IntegrityError exception.

**model**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    codice = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length = 13, default = '')
```

**form**

```
class NewTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    codice = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
```

**view**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewTicketForm(request.POST)
    form.codice = 'MC-PR' + get_random_string(length=8, allowed_chars='0123456789')
    if form.is_valid():
        while True:
            try:
                codice = 'MC-PR' + get_random_string(length=8, allowed_chars='0123456789')
                form.codice = codice
                form.save() 
            except:
                break
        form.save()
        return redirect('ticket-homepage')
else:
    form = NewTicketForm()
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'ticket/new_ticket_form.html', context)
```

I also tried to set form.code before form.is_valid () but the exception is raised anyway. technically there shouldn't be any problems because I generate the value with get_random_string and try-except allows me to do it again as long as the value is not unique.

**traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)

The above exception ((1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'ticket_ticket.ticket_ticket_codice_f619a2bb_uniq'")) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/ticket/views.py", line 34, in createNewTicket
    form.save()
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 460, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/ticket/models.py", line 72, in save
    return super(Ticket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/var/www/framework_mc/framework_mc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /ticket/new-ticket/
Exception Value: (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'ticket_ticket.ticket_ticket_codice_f619a2bb_uniq'")
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Answered below, as a comment I would suggest to remove `default = ''` from unique field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
while True:
    try:
        codice = 'MC-PR' + get_random_string(length=8, allowed_chars='0123456789')
        form.codice = codice
        form.save() 
        break  # <- it breaks while loop only if there is no Integrity error
    except IntegrityError:
        pass  # <- in case of Integrity error it will generate a new code and try again
```

Comment: this avoid the IntegrityError,  but apparently setting form.codice = 'something' and then doing form.save() doesn't work, the value remains empty. but that's another problem

Answer (score 0):

Use django [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal for setup codice:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save)
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.codice = 'MC-PR' + get_random_string(length=8, allowed_chars='0123456789')
```